# Apply pct function across multiple dataframes

Tags: r, lapply, invisible

First up thanks to who ever takes this question on. I have up to ten data frames that I want to apply the pct function to (from the caroline package). Due to the data I have, which causes an overflow error, I have to divide all the cells by 1000. Once this happens I can apply the pct function without an issue. Then I want to trim off the original data and create a new data frame.

I have managed to write the following function that does the correct thing except it does not save the results (may be it is lacking a return statement). Therefore I could do it long hand. However, that is not the most important thing.

```
 require (pct)
 finallist <- list(A, B)

 lapply(finallist , function (foo) {

 temp <-  as.data.frame(foo[,1])
 checks <- cbind(temp, foo[,2:480]/1000)
 checka <- pct(checks, tickerlist)
 foo <- checka[c(1, 481:959)]
 })
```

With the A and B Data frames being formed like this

```
  A  <- structure(list(mgrname = c("Man A", "Man A", "Man A", "Man B", "Man  B", "Man B", "Man C", "Man C", "Man C"), 
                  ticker = c("AAPL", "MSFT", "TLSA", "AAPL", "MSFT", "TLSA", "AAPL", "MSFT", "TLSA"), 
                  share = c(20L, 30L, 40L, 20L, 10L, 50L, 20L, 20L, 80L)), 
             .Names = c("mgrname", "ticker", "share"), 
             row.names = c(NA, -9L),
             class = "data.frame")
```

B would be same

The real key is to try and write new data frames out. The code that I started with uses the invisible function (I think it should have an assign function in there somewhere)

```
  invisible(lapply (names(finalist), 
              function (foo) assign (x = y, value =  temp <-     as.data.frame(foo[,1]),
                 checks <- cbind(temp, foo[,2:480]/1000),
                 checka <- pct(checks, tickerlist),
                 foo <- checka[c(1, 481:959)] , envir =.GlobalEnv)))
```

But it says

```
  Error in lapply(names(finalist), function(foo) assign(x = y, value = temp <- as.data.frame(foo[,  : 
   object 'finalist' not found
```

The final data frame should hopefully look like this

```
  | mgrname | APPL   | MSFT  | TLSA  |
  |---------|--------|-------|-------|
  | Man A   | .33    |  .5   | .23   |
  | Man B   | .33    |  .16  | .30   |
  | Man C   | .33    |  .33  | .47   |
```

Comment: It looks like you define an object `finallist` with two `l`s, but then in your `lapply` you use `finalist` with just one `l`. Since you never defined `finalist` with one `l` you get the object not found error.

Comment: You've got a good thing going with a list of data frames, I don't know why you're mucking about with `assign` inside your `lapply` - keep using lists. The `x = y` argument to `assign` is particularly strange since `y` doesn't seem to change. Also, are you missing some curly braces? You seem to give `assign` an awful lot of arguments, `x = y`, `value = temp <- ...`, `checks <- ...`. It's usually considered bad form (and unnecessary) to use `<-` within a function argument...

Comment: When you do `function(foo)`, `foo` is the name of the input to the function, you seem to be using it as the output. I think your example is somewhat obscured by using identical `A` and `B` inputs. If your data frames really have the same structure, you would probably do better to combine them into one data frame and use `dplyr` or `data.table` to operate on it by group.

Comment: I tried to install the pct package, but the message was "not available for R version 3.3.2".  Is there another source of the package?

Comment: LawyeR - that is annoying about pct not being available. Ultimately, the pct function is not really the important part. The important process is trimming columns from the data frame and then writing it out to a new data frame (or overwrite the existing dataf rame). I hope that makes sense

Comment: Gregor - the reason I have the same data structure is that each data frame is for a particular quarter and I need to get the data into a matrix form with the stock tickers as columns and mangers as rows. Therefore there is no room for a date column, this is dealt with in the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this code worked.

First do the manipulations

```
 newlist <- lapply(finallist , function (foo) {
 temp <-  as.data.frame(foo[,1])
 checks <- cbind(temp, foo[,2:4]/100)
 checka <- pct(checks, c("AAPL", "MSFT", "TLSA"))
 foo <- checka[c(1, 5:7)]
 })
```

Then use this. Namings etc are a bit off but I think I can handle that.

```
lapply(seq_along(newlist), 
   function(i,x) {assign(paste0("a",i),x[[i]], envir=.GlobalEnv)},
   x=newlist)
```